# How to apply changes to Zeppelin env and site in Amazon EMR?

Tags: amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to apply changes to the Zeppelin environmental values in my EMR after launch but it is not working. The changes I am trying to add are as below taken from https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/setup/storage/storage.html

```
zeppelin-env.sh: (from /etc/zeppelin/conf/ and /etc/zeppelin/conf.dist/)
export ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_S3_CANNED_ACL=BucketOwnerFullControl

Or zeppelin-site.xml: (from /etc/zeppelin/conf/ and /etc/zeppelin/conf.dist/)
<property>
  <name>zeppelin.notebook.s3.cannedAcl</name>
  <value>BucketOwnerFullControl</value>
  <description>Saves notebooks in S3 with the given Canned Access Control List.</description>
</property>
```

As in the text block, I tried overwriting both the files in conf and conf.dist and then
sudo systemctl stop zeppelin and start. But whenever I re-enter Zeppelin and look at the configurations page I can confirm that the changes did not take effect (also tested). I am not sure what is going on.

How do I add environmental or site values on a running EMR? I'd prefer doing it in a paragraph, but that doesn't seem possible. I am using EMR 5.30.1 if that adds any context.

Update: Zeppelin 0.82 does not support cannedACL settings. Support started from Zeppelin 0.9 which starts with EMR 5.33.0. BUT still does not work.
I can use aws api to upload a file to the other account bucket and it works fine when I add the ACL there, but not in Zeppelin, even when the change reflects in the Configuration page. And this goes for Zepp 0.9 and 0.10. What is going on? Why does this not work? I'm doing a simple df.write.parquet